# Relationship Laravel API

Tags: php, laravel

## The Problem

There might be an easier way to do this, I might be complicating it.

I have `Articles` and `Comments`. I set up an **API**.

However, I need `Articles` to have many comments and a `Comment` to have one Article.

---

## What I tried:

The First thing I did was to go to the `Article` model and insert this function:

```
public function comment()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Comment');
}
```

And on `Comment` model:

```
public function article()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Article', 'article_id');
}
```

Problem with the approach above is that I have no clue how to go about it on the controller. I was returning a json response from the call out, but decided to go with a transformer instead.

Below is my `CommentController` store function.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    return Comment::create($request->all());
}
```

How can I tell it which comment belongs to what article and how to update it on the article that we have one or more comments?

After that I decided to go the "manual" route and insert a field on `Article` called `'comments_id'`, changed it to array on the Model, but I don't know how to update that array on the `Article`.

This is what I got.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $article = Article::findOrFail($request->article_id);

    $article->update(array_add($request->id));

    return Comment::create($request->all());
}
```

This is the error response:

```
"Missing argument 2 for array_add(), called in /var/www/html/larapi/app/Http/Controllers/CommentController.php on line 26 and defined"
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are creating a comment you just need to make sure that it has an `article_id` value.

After that when you run the following you should see your comment(s):

`Article::comments->get();`

Comment: How would I add that on a transformer?

Comment: What I mean is, let's say I wanna show which article the comment belong to. I tried `Comment::article->get()` but I get this error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '->' `

Answer (score 0):

Your first idea was sufficient, don't do a comments_id column in your Article!

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    return Comment::create($request->all());
}
```

After that you can just use `$comment->article` to get the Article model which relates to `$comment` or if you have an `$article` you get the comments by `$article->comment`. (I would rename it to `comments` btw, normally you use plural for `hasMany` for obvious reasons.)

So basically if you want to have all comments in a view, you would just fetch the Article via `Article::find($id)` or rather just let Laravel do the work via implicit binding

```
public function show(Article $article)
{
    return view('article.show', compact('article'));
}
```

And in your blade template you can then just iterate over comments like

```
foreach ($article->comments as $comment) {
    // stuff
}
```

PS I just reread to see if I missed anything... you wanted an API :P I am sorry, I have a meeting now, I will update my answer later, but maybe this will help you a little bit already

Edit
Does not change anything, just use $article->comments to get a collection of all comments of that article and then return it as json.